# Why isn't my Sequelize DB syncing with V6?

Tags: javascript, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am using the setup [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62628134/239879) and when I try to:

```
const sequelize = require('./db').getConnection()
....
await sequelize.sync()
    console.log("sync done")
```

I get no error, but it doesn't actually create the tables in my DB. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried using the option `force: true` in the sync function? Had a similar issue when I first started using sequelize and iirc that was how I fixed it. If that doesn't work though, you may need to change the way you initialise your DB.

Comment: you can take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/69431362/6183464

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for it to sync properly
you need to use

```
sequelize.sync({alter:true})
```

please include the alter flag as true in sync function